# Магия setInterval и рукописный слайдер. Слишком длинная задержка при показе первого слайда

Tags: javascript, setinterval

Вот рабочий слайдер, который меняет кадры каждые 3 секунды... по идее. По факту же при первом запуске интервал составляет в два раза больше, т.е. 6 секунд. И так всегда, когда загружается страница/код, первый интервал в 2 раза больше установленного, это можно наблюдать.

Как исправить?

```js
var slider = {
  // Принимает данные:
  // slide - элементы, которые будут "перемещаться",
  // band - лента содержащая элементы, она на самом деле перемещается
  take: function(slide, band, interval) {

    // Если не объявлен, выставляем по умолчанию
    interval = (interval) ? interval : 3000;

    // Находим нужные элементы
    var slides = $(slide);
    var film = $(band);

    // Если не существует таких объектов, завершаем функцию
    if (!slides[0] && !film[0]) {
      return;
    }

    // Для перемещений, номер активного элемента
    var numder = 0;

    // Ловим контекст
    var cnxFunc = this;

    // Повторяем через определенное время
    setInterval(function() {

      // Приводим в движение ленту
      cnxFunc.mover(numder, slides, film);

      // Шагаем на следующую. Если дошли до конца, то начинаем сначала
      (numder === slides.length - 1) ? numder = 0: numder++;
    }, interval);
  },
  mover: function(numder, slides, film) {

    // Отступ
    var shift = [];
    shift[0] = 0;

    // Присваиваем значения отступов для каждой картинки
    for (var i = 1; i < slides.length; i++) {
      shift.push(slides.eq(i - 1).width());
      shift[i] += shift[i - 1];
    }

    // Анимированное перемещение
    film.animate({
      left: -shift[numder]
    }, 500);
  }
};
slider.take('.slide', '.band')
```

```css
.window {
  width: 300px;
  height: 185px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.band {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide_1 {
  background: #fcf;
}

.slide_2 {
  background: #cff;
}

.slide_3 {
  background: #ffc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='window'>
  <div class='band'>
    <div class='slide slide_1'></div>
    <div class='slide slide_2'></div>
    <div class='slide slide_3'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `первый интервал в 2 раза больше установленного` - поменяй местами `cnxFunc.mover(numder, slides, film);` и `(numder === slides.length - 1) ? numder = 0: numder++;`

Comment: `как он работает как сумасшедший, интервал в несколько раз меньше установленного или даже нулевой` - и сколько надо ждать? день? два?))

Comment: Обалдеть! Точно! Просто мы ведь выставляем на первом элементе и setInterval когда срабатывает, переводит на первый элемент (numder = 0), можно даже не менять местами, а написать numder = 1 и тогда все работает правильно. Спасибо большое!

Comment: А фиг знает, с секундомером не засекал, но определенно так глючит периодически. Я не знаю, от чего это зависит и потому не могу сказать, но вот даже сейчас с обновленным кодом, только что глючил так.

Comment: `но определенно так глючит периодически.` - Скорее всего что-то со скоростью интернет соединения... ибо лично я ничего такого не смог воспроизвести проблему со скоростью

Comment: Я думаю, дело не в скорости, потому что код выполняется стационарно. На данном примере, я тоже пока не наблюдаю подобного глюка, видимо этот глюк возникает не в этой части (я скинул не весь код, там еще код кнопок навигации есть), похоже ошибка возникает там. Давай сделаем так, я форматирую вопрос чтобы там была только решенная проблема про двойной первый интервал, ты на него ответишь, я отмечу как ответ. А остальное буду в новом вопросе задавать

Comment: Исправил, можешь ответить

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setInterval работает нормально в вашем примере, просто вы в первой итерации включаете 1 слайд, который уже включен. (в интервале плюсуется после mover):

```js
var start = Date.now();

var slider = {
  // Принимает данные:
  // slide - элементы, которые будут "перемещаться",
  // band - лента содержащая элементы, она на самом деле перемещается
  take: function(slide, band, interval) {

    // Если не объявлен, выставляем по умолчанию
    interval = interval || 3000;

    // Находим нужные элементы
    var slides = $(slide);
    var film = $(band);

    // Если не существует таких объектов, завершаем функцию
    if (!slides[0] && !film[0]) {
      return;
    }

    // Для перемещений, номер активного элемента
    var numder = 0;

    // Ловим контекст
    var cnxFunc = this;

    // Повторяем через определенное время
    setInterval(function() {
      console.log(Math.round((Date.now() - start)/1000));
      // Шагаем на следующую. Если дошли до конца, то начинаем сначала
      (numder === slides.length - 1) ? numder = 0: numder++;
      
      // Приводим в движение ленту
      cnxFunc.mover(numder, slides, film);
    }, interval);
  },
  mover: function(numder, slides, film) {

    // Отступ
    var shift = [0];

    // Присваиваем значения отступов для каждой картинки
    for (var i = 1; i < slides.length; i++) {
      shift.push(slides.eq(i - 1).width());
      shift[i] += shift[i - 1];
    }

    // Анимированное перемещение
    film.animate({
      left: -shift[numder]
    }, 500);
  }
};
slider.take('.slide', '.band')
```

```css
.window {
  width: 300px;
  height: 185px;
  background: #ccc;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.band {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.slide {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.slide_1 {
  background: #fcf;
}

.slide_2 {
  background: #cff;
}

.slide_3 {
  background: #ffc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='window'>
  <div class='band'>
    <div class='slide slide_1'></div>
    <div class='slide slide_2'></div>
    <div class='slide slide_3'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```